# Include timestamp in hash, but how to compare hashes?

Tags: algorithm, security, rest

A client creates a hash that includes following information

- Request url
- Request method

A secret key is used to create a hash from this information. He sends this hash together with his public key to the server which retrieves the clients secret key from database. Now the server creates its own hash and if the hashes match the accessing application is authorized.

However when I add

- Timestamp

to the hash. How can I compare the hashes serverside? The hashes will be different since the server creates the hash milliseconds later. Say I want to trust the client only if the request is made within 30 seconds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the timestamp along with the hash so you can compute the hash and compare the value of the timestamp against current time to verify your specified 30 second window.

Comment: yeah seems to be the only way

Comment: You could alternatively not send the timestamp with the hash, and attempt to compute every possible hash with every possible timestamp within 30 seconds of the current time, but obviously there can be a performance concern there.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to, rather than having millisecond or second precision for your timestamp, instead use a 30 second precision, i.e. for 30 seconds, each timestamp will be the same.

Thus, during 30 seconds after the request was sent, there's at most 2 timestamp possible. You can simply calculate both on the server and check if the hash matches either.

The disadvantage here is that there will be a 30 second range - you'll accept some 60 second old requests and reject some 31 second old requests. But, if you're happy with that... (you can also have higher precision for your timestamp, at the cost of having to calculate more hashes).

And there will obviously be a performance impact for having to calculate 2 hashes for every request.

Comment: Also client and server must agree on what the current time is.